# Forgot to add files to commit then merged with other branch but found lost commit unreachable files [git]

Tags: git

My problem might be a bit specific.
I made some changes, forgot to add most of them and then committed my code thinking everything was saved. Lucky me, I noticed something was wrong when git asked me to merge to the remote branch so I did a correct a commit after adding my files. But after that (dumb me) I went back my commit **without** my changes and merged with the remote branch there.

So after some search on the web I found how to search for unreachable blobs/commits in git and I found my correct commit.
Is there a way to apply this commit? Do I need to modify it? For now it is stored in a file.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found a solution after a few more searches. (I thought it would be much more complicated).
Here is the [solution I found](http://gitready.com/advanced/2009/01/17/restoring-lost-commits.html).
It seems like you can still apply a lost commit like mine with it's SHA-1 code. So the only I thing I needed to do was get the 8 first characters (i.e. 39ba87b) of the hash of my commit and use the command : `git merge 39ba87b`